# Does Google Index Images with no file extensions?

Tags: image, url-rewriting, seo

I'm evaluating the possibility to rewrite URLs for my images from

```
/img/myfilename.jpg
```

to

```
/img/myfilename
```

I have done some test and in the browser the `/img/myfilename` displays correctly an image.
But I'm not sure if this can create seom SEO problem.
My question?

Does Google Index Images with no file extensions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It might be better seo to rewrite images to the root-folder.

www.domain.xyz/abcdef-dishwasher.jpg

or better

domain.xyz/abcdef-dishwasher.image

Additional keywords start now after 2 separators.

There are only resources on the web, no folders. So as long as you send the right HTTP Content-Type by HTTP Header, you can use what ever you want.

Here is an [example](http://www.fensterzumhof.eu/bilder/d/39210-5/Berlin_Kreuzberg_Auto_Mariannenplatz).

Try Google Image Search with: search-term -.jpg -.jpeg -.gif -.png

Comment: does not reply to my question

Comment: @GibboK See my changes. I have added an example.

Answer (score 0):

My guess would be that they will index it anyway.
Google has the best engineers in the field, I am sure they don't identify images by URL strings.

Your browser shows it correctly because it received an HTTP Content-Type header that defines the content as image content. Google *may* catch the same thing with their crawler and know it is an image.

The bottom line is that if a normal user is able to see it then you should assume the crawlers can also see it since this is the goal for those crawlers.

The correct approach is to either block content according to the HTTP `User-Agent` header, ask for exclusion of certain content using `robots.txt` and using the `rel="nofollow` tag attribute.